# Add extra class on basis of if ... else statement

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In a view, I'm trying to add an additional class specification "active" on basis of the page the user is on. I have:

```
<li <%= if current_page?(root_path) class="hvr-bottom active" : class="hvr-bottom" %>><a href=<%= root_path %>>Home</a></li>
```

This generates the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...
```

*How should I adjust the code to add the additional class only if a specific page is visited?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current ternary statement seems to be missing a `?`. Try the following:

```
<li class=<%= current_page?(root_path) ? "hvr-bottom active" : "hvr-bottom" %>> ... </li>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense. Unfortunately, still an error message: `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...tive" : "hvr-bottom" );@output_buffer.safe_append='... ... `. The line I have is: `<li class=<%= if current_page?(root_path) ? "hvr-bottom active" : "hvr-bottom" %>> <a href=<%= root_path %>>Home</a> </li>`.

Comment: Oh duh, sorry my mistake. Remove the `if`. You don't need that with a ternary operation. Updating answer :)

Comment: Yes, then the page renders without error. However, it does not seem to have assigned it the `active` class type; only `hvr-bottom` (also checked this with the inspector). I don't understand why. The line exists in a partial `_header.html.erb`. This partial is called on in a view page. The method `current_page` is used throughout the application without problems.

Comment: Oh, and it does work if I write it as `<% if current_page?(root_path) %>` `<li class="hvr-bottom active"><a href=<%= root_path %>>Home</a></li>` `<% else %>` `<li class="hvr-bottom"><a href=<%= root_path %>>Home</a></li>` `<% end %>`. I guess I'll just use that then.